# How to make sure recycler view adapter item takes full height of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a recyclerview which contains many items.

But the first item is like an intro screen, it has a button on which user can tap to view more, or user can scroll to view more data.

Something like following.

[image]

I want this button to be at the bottom of screen, in small devices it is not visible unless user scrolls the view. So basically layout is taking more height, so user has to scroll to view the complete layout.

I am using constraint layout, and connect it to the bottom of the view.

There are only 2 items in the view, 1 is imageView, which does not have any image, I have only added background color to it, and other is a TextView.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
 
 
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/Black_Color"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        
        
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</
```

Comment: Need more detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

*in small devices it is not visible unless user scrolls the view* - sounds like your image is taking a lot of screen height in small devices so the user must scroll trow the screen

If you want to "disable" the scrolling behavior of your item and put everything inside a screen (without views gong out of the screen and thus making the user scroll) you can change your layout so your item will only occupy the given screen height and not more, and by doing so you will not have this problem on small devices.

something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.9"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The trick was to simply give the image height in percentage like this

```
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.9"
```

And now your image will take 90% height on every screen size.